# Agora SwiftUI OpenLive Integration issues

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, agora.io

I'm trying to implement Agora to my existing SwiftUI app, I used this tutorial to implement it https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-iOS-Tutorial-SwiftUI-1to1
My Intention is to have a OpenLive video calls where I have only one Broadcaster and many audience to view it (similar to Instagram Live). unfortunately, I only found documentation on how to make a 1-1 video call and I was not able to let Audience join the channel and preview the live video stream.

This is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AgoraRtcKit

var isCurrentStreamer = true
struct AgoraView : View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userDefaultData: UserDefaultDetails
    
    @State var isLocalInSession = true
    @State var isLocalAudioMuted = false
    
    @State var isRemoteInSession = true
    @State var isRemoteVideoMuted = false
    
    let localCanvas = VideoCanvas()
    let remoteCanvas = VideoCanvas()
    
    private let videoEngine = VideoEngine()
    private var rtcEngine: AgoraRtcEngineKit {
        get {
            return videoEngine.agoraEngine
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            
            VideoSessionView(
                backColor: Color("c2"),
                backImage: Image("big_logo"),
                hideCanvas: false,
                canvas: isCurrentStreamer ? localCanvas:remoteCanvas
            ).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
        }.onAppear {
                self.agoraLive(role: self.userDefaultData.AgoraRole, channelID: self.userDefaultData.currentAuctionId)
        }
    }
}





fileprivate extension AgoraView {
    
    func agoraLive(role: AgoraClientRole, channelID: String){
        // init AgoraRtcEngineKit
        videoEngine.AgoraView = self
        rtcEngine.enableDualStreamMode(false)
        rtcEngine.setVideoEncoderConfiguration(
            AgoraVideoEncoderConfiguration(
                size: AgoraVideoDimension640x360,
                frameRate: .fps15,
                bitrate: AgoraVideoBitrateStandard,
                orientationMode: .adaptative
            )
        )
        
        if role == .broadcaster {
            rtcEngine.enableVideo()
            addLocalSession()
            rtcEngine.startPreview()
        }else{
            addLocalSession()
            rtcEngine.startPreview()
            
        }
        
    
        rtcEngine.joinChannel(byToken: Token, channelId: channelID, info: nil, uid: 0, joinSuccess: nil)
        
        // Step 6, set speaker audio route
        rtcEngine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true)
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    func addLocalSession() {
        let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
        if self.userDefaultData.AgoraRole == .broadcaster {
            videoCanvas.view = localCanvas.rendererView
        }else {
            videoCanvas.view = remoteCanvas.rendererView
        }
        videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
        if isCurrentStreamer {
            rtcEngine.setupLocalVideo(videoCanvas)
        }else{
            rtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The OpenLive example code is in another repo: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Broadcasting/tree/master/OpenLive-iOS.

Comment: I tried implementing OpenLive into my swiftui project and it didn't work for the audience part. I was able to broadcast but not view as audience.

Comment: Understood. Does the OpenLive example project work? That's the starting point, and then bring over the pieces one by one into your project. I've just gone through this exact process bringing over custom audio for multi-party calls in Agora. Their docs are not always completely clear, and you should start with their example project. Ignore SwiftUI for the moment, and get the call working.

Comment: But to your SwiftUI code, remember that SwiftUI Views are recreated all the time. They're data, not objects. So your current code is going to create a lot of independent VideoCanvas and VideoEngine, which is probably not what you mean. At a minimum, those should be marked `@State`, but as much of possible, avoid creating objects (classes) inside of a View. Just pass in the pieces you need.

Comment: The Call works fine for broadcasting only, but when I try to retrieve the broadcast as audience the video doesn't show in the view. I tried two tutorials so fast both have same issue. Agora-iOS-Tutorial-SwiftUI-1to1 and OpenLive-iOS

Comment: If their sample code doesn't work out of the box, I would discuss that with Agora.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't hooking up the remote video view correctly. In order to see a remote user's video, you need to create a `AgoraRtcVideoCanvas` with that remote user's UID, and then pass it into `setupRemoteVideo`. What you're doing is trying to set up a remote view before you've even joined the call, and have no idea who is in it.

You need to implement the [remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/oc/Protocols/AgoraRtcEngineDelegate.html#//api/name/rtcEngine:remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid:state:reason:elapsed:) callback on the `AgoraRtcEngineDelegate` in order to get the remote user's UID and hook it up to your canvas correctly.

Something like this:

```
extension AgoraView: AgoraRtcEngineDelegate {
    func rtcEngine(_ engine: AgoraRtcEngineKit, remoteVideoStateChangedOfUid uid: UInt, state: AgoraVideoRemoteState, reason: AgoraVideoRemoteStateReason, elapsed: Int) {
        if state == .starting {
            let videoCanvas = AgoraRtcVideoCanvas()
            videoCanvas.view = remoteCanvas.rendererView
            videoCanvas.uid = uid
            videoCanvas.renderMode = .hidden
            rtcEngine.setupRemoteVideo(videoCanvas)
        }
    }
}
```

If you did the above as written, you'd have to set the AgoraView as the rtcEngine's delegate when you initialize it, as well.

If you're using the demo app provided, `VideoEngine` is currently set up as the delegate, and is doing this in `firstRemoteVideoDecodedOfUid` (which is now deprecated). It's likely that this code is not correctly hooked up to your SwiftUI views.